# Can I have multiple model representations in Django

Tags: django, django-models

My questions is whether or not I can have multiple model represntations in Django. More specifically I am using a post_save signal to do something after a model has been saved. The problem is that the signal passes an instance of the saved model but that's only the unicode representation. This is because I have overriden the **unicode** method. I want to keep this method for the admin panel but for other purposes I need access to full representation of the model.

So how can I pass a different representation for the model in the signal and different in the admin panel?

Comment: Proxy Models maybe? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

Comment: But that means I need to subclass my model which is not desired in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `post_save` signal carries actual instance that has been saved.

See the [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L640) for reference.

If you're sure it is unicode, please share django version.